# Modify AxesRange

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to modify the range of the axes. The axes should only show the range from 0 to 1. The plot contains a text item (name of HalfLine) witch disappears when I add PlotRange, but if I don't add PlotRange, the axes reach into the negativ area.
The following Code and picture should be modified

Code

```
Plot[{3 x (1 - x), x}, {x, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}},
 Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1}, {0, 0.5, 1}},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30, FontFamily -> "Times" , Black, Bold},
 ImageSize -> Full,
 Epilog -> {{Black,Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(\"\<*\>\"\)]\)",
Bold, 20], {2/3, -0.04}], FontSize -> 30,
Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}], Line[{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}]}, 
{Black, Dashed, Line[{{2/3, 0}, {2/3, 1}}]}}]
```

The Plot
[image: Plot with text "x^*"]

If I add PlotRange to the code the name of the HalfLine disappears

Changed Code

```
Plot[{3 x (1 - x), x}, {x, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}},
 Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1}, {0, 0.5, 1}},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30, FontFamily -> "Times" , Black, Bold},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
 ImageSize -> Full,
 Epilog -> {{Black, 
    Text[
     Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(\"\<*\>\"\)]\)", Bold, 
      20], {2/3, -0.04}], FontSize -> 30, Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
    Line[{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}]}, {Black, Dashed,  
    Line[{{2/3, 0}, {2/3, 1}}]}}
 ]
```

[image: Plot without Text item]

I also tried AxedEdge but this isn't a option for plot. I even tried this:

```
p = Plot[{3 x (1 - x), x}, {x, 0, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}},
  Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1}, {0, 0.5, 1}},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", 
    "\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"f\", \"\\\"r\\\"\"},\n\
\"IndexedDefault\"]\)(x)"},
  
  AxesStyle -> Thick,
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30, FontFamily -> "Times" , Black, 
    Bold},
  
  ImageSize -> Full,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  Epilog -> {{Black, Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
     Line[{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}]}, {Black, Dashed,  
     Line[{{2/3, 0}, {2/3, 1}}]}} ]

Show[p, Epilog -> {Text[
    Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(\"\<*\>\"\)]\)", Bold, 
     20], {2/3, -0.04}], FontSize -> 30} ]
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

With a few modifications especially using `Frame`:

```
Plot[{3 x (1 - x), x}
  , {x, 0, 1}
 , Frame -> True
  , PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}}
 , FrameTicks -> {
   {Range[0, 1.0, 0.5], {None}}
   , {Range[0, 1.0, 0.5]~
     Join~{{2/3, 
       Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(\"\<*\>\"\)]\)", Bold, 
        20]}}, {None}}
   }
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}
 , ImagePadding -> {{60, 20}, {60, 20}}
  , LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}
  , ImageSize -> 600
 , Epilog -> {
      {Black
    (*, Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(\"\<*\>\"\)]\)", 
    Bold, 20], {2/3,-0.04}]*)
    , FontSize -> 30
    (*, Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]
    , Line[{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}]*)
    }
   , {Black, Dashed, Line[{{2/3, 0}, {2/3, 1}}]}
      }
  ]
```

[image]